# Как изменить рейтинг текущему пользователю, когда он сделает запрос на конкретный адрес

Tags: php, yii2, phpmyadmin, php7

как изменить рейтинг текущему пользователю, когда он сделает запрос на конкретный адрес.
каждый раз, когда он обращается на адрес, к рейтингу добавляешь 0.01
/rating/add-rating

```
private function actionAddRating(){
//        $person = Persone::user();
        /** @var User $user */
//        $user = \Yii::$app->user->identity;
//        $user = \Yii::$app->user-persons;
        $person = \Yii::$app->user->identity->person;
        $person->updateCounters(['rating' => 0.01]);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->user->username) {
            return   $person->updateCounters(['rating' => 0.01]);
        }
        return false;
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно проверять `post`. сделайте это отдельным методом и вызывайте этот метод в вашем акшион методе:

```
   /*
    * Method update counters
    * @return bool
    */
    private function addRating(){
            //обычно User::
            $person = Persone::findOne(\Yii::$app->user->identity->id);
            $person->updateCounters(['rating' => 0.01]);
            //у вас модель основная осталась неизменной просто сохраняем
            $persons->save(false);
            //возвращаем true что сохранили апдейт 
            return true;
        } 
//как то так

public function actionIndex(){
    $this->addRating();
    //...
}
```

Comment: а если Persone не статический?

Comment: он не статичный у мееня